# INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE, due to file that is I have to delete everytime

Tags: android, adb

I used to be able to do adb install test.apk from the consol (or even eclipse) with no issues. I rooted my phone yesterday and then I started getting

**Error**

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]
```

After a lot of trial and error, I found out that the error behind it is that it says "couldn't rename /data/app/test-1.apk

So I went to that folder and indeed there was a file called test-1.apk. I deleted it and I was able to execute adb install successfully. However, I have to do the same procedure everytime I run adb install (delete the apk file)

I am suspecting that it is permission thingy that adb is not able to rename test-1.apk or remove it due to permission. How can I fix that?

Or if you have another suggestion all togther, please help

Comment: Is is this on device or emulator?

Comment: What happens if you do an adb uninstall <packagename> first?

Comment: adb uninstall test.apk does not execute. It just shows "Failure"

Comment: Check your rooting guide / forum / ... you used for infos about permission problems. Maybe you forgot some step.

Comment: adb uninstall takes the package name as the argument, not the apk.

Comment: I used the package name, same error :(